# Exhausted in German

Tags: difference, adjective

What is the difference between the following adjectives:

- erschöpft sein
- erschlagen sein
- ausgelaugt sein

Do all of them mean *to be exhausted*?

Comment: What about the wonderful "ermattet"?

Answer (score 4):

Ich antworte auf Deutsch, weil ich mich in meiner Muttersprache besser ausdrücken kann als in Englisch.

Die drei Begriffe bedeuten, auf Menschen übertragen, tatsächlich dasselbe. Ihre ursprüngliche Bedeutung ist aber unterschiedlich:

### Erschöpft

Das Wort »*schöpfen*« (engl. “to scoop”, “to ladle”) bedeutet, dass man eine Flüssigkeit (z.B. Wasser, Milch, Wein) mit einem kleinem Gefäß (häufig mit einem Schöpfer) aus einem größeren (z.B. aus einem Fass oder einem Brunnen) entnimmt.

Wenn man das immer wieder macht, wird das große Gefäß irgendwann leer. Es ist dann ***erschöpft***.

Wenn also ein Behälter, eine Resourcenquelle oder ein Reservoire erschöpft ist, dann ist es leer.

Im übertragenen Sinn bedeutet das, dass eine Person nicht mehr in der Lage ist noch Leistung zu erbringen. Die Person ist erschöpft (sie hat keine Energie mehr).

### Erschlagen

Die englische Übersetzung von »*erschlagen*« ist »*to strike dead*«. Ein Mensch, der erschlagen *wurde* ist also tot. Er ist durch einen heftigen Schlag gestorben.

Wenn aber jemand erschlagen *ist*, dann gilt das im übertragenen Sinn: Die Person fühlt sich so, als wäre sie von einem heftigen Schlag beinahe getötet worden. Eine Person, die sich so fühlt, hat sich zuvor verausgabt, oder ist aufgrund anderer Ereignisse in einem Zustand, in dem sie nicht mehr fähig ist, Leistung zu erbringen.

### Ausgelaugt

Die englische Übersetzung für »auslaugen« ist »leach out«. Das Wort wird im Deutschen meistens als Partizip Perfekt Passiv benutzt. Es bedeutet: Mit Wasser oder einer anderen Flüssigkeit einen Inhaltsstoff aus einer Probe herauslösen.

Wer Kaffee (das Getränk) zubereitet, laugt mit heißem Wasser das Koffein gemeinsam mit Farb- und Geschmacksstoffen aus dem gemahlenem Kaffeepulver.

Wenn dieser Vorgang zu lange ausgeführt wird, sind irgendwann alle Inhaltsstoffe aus der Probe herausgelaugt. Die Probe ist dann ***ausgelaugt***.

Im übertragenen Sinn gilt dasselbe, wie im Fall von »*erschöpft sein*«.

Answer (score 0):

It’s interesting (and never occurred to me) how the different languages use different concepts for *exhaustion*. The English word derives from *to exhaust*, meaning to get rid of gases (compare the car’s *exhaust*) and nicely pictures how your power leaves the body while breathing. German uses different concepts.

*Erschöpft* is easily the most standard *exhausted*, i.e. the one one would find in a dictionary. As Hubert nicely explained in German, it derives from the picture of a container of liquid being scooped empty. Since scooping happens bit by bit, the exhaustion will overcome the exhausted person slowly — which fits the picture, because if you’re running, you don’t suddenly fall over after being completely fine the second before.

*Ausgelaugt* follows a similar picture, only that the power was *leached out* of the person.

*Ermattet*, the word given in a comment to the question, is a little bit dated or higher-register but still means the same. It derives from *matt werden*, i.e. to become faint — much like a picture faints over time. Other than that, the usage is the same.

---

*Erschlagen* is distinctly different from the other words in the series. As Hubert elaborated, it means *to be struck dead* and would usually be used if a person was killed by being hit with a blunt object. The figurative meaning in the sense of *exhausted* is less prominent than for the others (and most notably: the literal meaning is a lot more present than any of the other three literal meanings, if only due to newspaper reports) but it *cannot* directly mean the slow exhaustion that one usually gets from excersizing. It would usually be taken to mean that one is overpowered suddenly by a lot of things happening at once. Examples:

- If a hundred e-mails land in your inbox within ten minutes, it’s safe to say

  > Ich bin von E-Mails *erschlagen*.
- If all went well for a long time, but suddenly problems are appearing everywhere, one can say

  > Ich bin so *erschlagen* (von Problemen).
- If one has just finished a marathon, one cannot say

  > <strike>Ich bin vom Laufen erschlagen.</strike>

  but rather

  > Ich fühle mich *wie erschlagen*.